# Word Problem on annual tax rate.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Summervile family took out a \$215, 000, 30 year mortage at an APR of 5.5%

The assessed value of the house is \$199,700. The annual property tax rate is \$13.15 per $1000 of assessed value. What is the annual property tax?

How can I proceed to solve this.

Comment: Try to see it this way: Apples cost $\$~13.15$ per $1~000$ apples. How much will $199~700$ apples cost?

Comment: @matti P. Then what is the purpose of first line."The Summervile family took out a \$215, 000, 30 year mortage at an APR of 5.5%" Dont we have to use it somewhere?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I don't see how the first line is relevant to answering the question related to the annual property tax.

Comment: @matti P. Thanks a lot for your response. Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

What does the mortgage have to do with it?  Multiply the tax rate by the assessed value.  You have to get the units right.